# Finding parent nodes based on double value of child node in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, nodes, jcr

I'm writing an XPath query to run against my JCR. I must retrieve all parent nodes of a certain type in a certain directory that also have a specific child node with a double property within a given range.

I've successfully filtered the directory and type of the parent but am having trouble adding a constraint to the child nodes. Additionally, the below code will return the child nodes but I want the parent nodes.

```
/jcr:root/content//element(*, parentnode:type)[parentnode:property = 'value']/element(*, childnode:type)[childnode:property > 0 and childnode:property < 5]
```

My current code gives me an empty set. I expect to receive the list of parentnode:type nodes that fit my constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "/.." to select the node before the current one.

> /jcr:root/content//element(*, parentnode:type)[parentnode:property =
>   'value']/element(*, childnode:type)[childnode:property > 0 and
>   childnode:property < 5]/..